# Does C supports compiler directive that prints a message without issuing warning or error?

Tags: c

The purpose was to print a message while compiling that acts as a reminder and it should not cause warning or error.

For e.g

```
void stub()
{
 // print a message say "TODO: Implement this before committing the changes"
}
```

Used `#warning` without `strict` option but it was still giving warning message.

Comment: No. My solution is to add a comment formatted `//TODO ` and then a shell script which collects all of them into a report.

Comment: @AaronDigulla this is an useful idea